# Modifying a ribbon control at runtime

Tags: c++, controls, runtime, ribbon, uiribbon

I'm using the [Windows Ribbon Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371191%28VS.85%29.aspx) in an unmanaged C++ application in Visual Studio.
Is it possible to add a button or other control at runtime? I can set up my ribbon using IUIFramework::LoadUI, but I can't modify it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to add or remove a button at runtime, **but** you may hide or show a *Tab* or *Group* at run time using *Application Modes* **and** you can set any button texts and images at runtime.

So you can declare and use multi-purpose buttons that will show only when a specific *Application Mode* is set and contain runtime defined texts and images.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch modes at runtime depending on what is defined in the markup - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940486%28VS.85%29.aspx#switching) for details:

> After modes are defined in markup,
>   they can be easily enabled or disabled
>   in response to contextual events. As
>   mentioned previously, Ribbon
>   applications always start in the
>   default mode 0. After the application
>   has initialized and mode 0 is active,
>   the set of active modes can be changed
>   by calling the IUIFramework::SetModes
>   function.

There is a comment [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2009/12/23/windows-ribbon-for-winforms-part-0-table-of-contents.aspx) to the effect that changes at runtime are quite limited - this is in regard to a third-party wrapper, note.

> You can dynamically add items at
>   runtime only to the galleries
>   controls:
>
> ComboBox, SplitButtonGallerty,
>   DropDownGallery and InRibbonGallery
>
> If you know what you want to add from
>   advance you can use ContextualTabs and
>   ApplicationModes to change the
>   visibility of (predefined) tabs and
>   groups.
>
> Unfortunately, you can add dynamically
>   groups at runtime.
>
> Note this is a limitation in the
>   Windows Ribbon Framework and not in
>   the wrapper library.

Comment: That solution doesn't work for me since I need to modify it in runtime and don't know what controls will be added in advance.

Comment: @sw - understood - runtime mods appear limited according to the latest MSDN docs.  Sorry...